# error: expected unqualified-id before pointer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

> **Edit : The issue was with the build system. It was compiling it as
>   c++, not c. Changed the build system and it worked like a charm!**

I am fairly new to data structures, and learned Linked List recently.
But when i am trying to implement on my own, I keep on getting this error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before 'new'
struct node *new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
             ^~~
```

I am trying to add an element at the end, and my structure and head is declared globally,
Here's my code:

```
struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *head;

void addNodeEnd(int data)
{
    struct node *new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data = data;
    new->next = NULL;
    // Some more code here, which makes the necessary links to existing linked list.
}
```

And inside main():

```
int main()
{
    addNodeEnd(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there something I am missing here? This is exactly what my professor did!

Comment: It looks like you're compiling it as C++ rather than C.  In C++, `new` is a keyword.

Comment: @TomKarzes  Oh, I changed the build system and it worked. Thanks a ton! Just curious, Searching online i came to know that even c++ files can have .c extension. Why did the developers chose to allow .c as valid extension for c++, even if it does not guarantee backwards compatibility in cases like this?

Comment: I'm not certain about the motivation, but I'd guess they just wanted to provide flexibility for the users.  Several different extensions are recognized as C++ source files.